# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

So I was trying to design the login page for my new app in Xamarin forms/ Cross-Platform Application.And Everything was going well until I tried to debug it and I got an error saying

> "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

[image: My code]

That's my code, also there error keeps saying it's on line 1

Comment: Please post code as text

Comment: At first glance everything looks correctly in your XAML. However as @PMerlet say please post source code as text with code behind as well.

Do you use stable version of Visual Studio or beta/alpha, Windows or Mac version?

Comment: Try enabling XAMLC.

Comment: What Exception? InnerException?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the problem is in your definition of [Thickness](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Thickness/#memberlist):

```
<OnIdeom.Tablet>140.150,140,0</OnIdeom.Tablet>
```

You should set left, top, right and bottom - 4 values all together. Alternatively you can set left/right and top/bottom - 2 values all together. However you have 3 values. So change it to:

```
<OnIdeom.Tablet>140.0, 150.0</OnIdeom.Tablet>
```

Or to:

```
<OnIdeom.Tablet>140, 150, 140, 0</OnIdeom.Tablet>
```

depends on your needs.

In order to get a better indication of a corrupted XAML use [XAMLC](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/).

Comment: It looks like the first period should possibly be a comma to provide four values.

Comment: for me, I set an empty value to BorderThickness="" RadButton from telerik,